# calculating the contribution of a variable to the growth of a total in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, statistics

I am currently trying to compute the contribution of a variable to the growth of a total.
The formula is the following :
On the period T - T' : the contribution of variable X to the growth of the total variable Y is defined like follows :

```
(Xt/Yt)*((Xt'-Xt)/Xt)*100
```

Here is my dataset :

```
 structure(list(regroupement = c("Aut", "Ort", 
"Rachis", "Chirurgie digestive", "Ophtalmo", "Uro-néphro", "Gynéco", ), actes_2019 = c(10, 
29520, 395, 14618, 5589, 6515, 4150, 866, 3458, 2137, 449, 0, 
575, 2180, 9179, 36079, 311, 388, 714, 4, 0, 6024, 4028), 
    actes_2021 = c(18, 24055, 106, 13735, 5505, 8196, 3376, 352, 
    3035, 2571, 511, 8, 689, 1134, 6504), sejours_2020 = c(2, 4946, 34, 2220, 
    1819, 1220, 574, 94, 801, 554, 140, 1, 221), sejours_2021 = c(7, 
    5144, 21)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L), core = structure(list(
    regroupement = c("Aut", "Ort",
    "Div", "Ac", "Obst", 
    "IVG", "Néo", "Séan"), actes_2019 = c(10, 
    29520, 395, 14618, 5589, 6515, 4150, 866, 3458, 2137, 449, 
    0, 575, 2180, 9179, 36079), actes_2020 = c(8, 25451, 308, 12845, 
    4167, 7376, 2994, 337, 2206, 2107, 437, 4, 575, 1477, 7933, 
    ), actes_2021 = c(18, 24055, 106, 13735, 5505, 8196, 3376, 
    352, 3035, 2571, 511, 8, 689, 1134, 6504, 42333, 161, 272, 
    138, 7, 0, 4682), sejours_2020 = c(2, 4946, 34, 2220, 1819, 
    1220, 574, 94, 801, 554, 140, 1, 221, ), sejours_2021 = c(7, 
    5144)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 4:30), tabyl_type = "two_way", totals = 
"row", class = c("tabyl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have computed for instance the contribution of the decline in the number of acts between 2020 and 2021 of the medical specialty "ortho" to the evolution of the total growth of the number of acts between these two years :

```
25451/107951 * ((24055 - 25451)/25451)*100
```

I would like to compute it for every specialty, on periods 2021-2020 and 2019-2021 in order to then plot a bar plot (not a stacked one), like the second one done here :
http://www.statapprendre.education.fr/insee/croissance/pourquoi/graphique.htm

I think a for loop would be advisable, but i don't really know how to proceed. Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    filter(regroupement != "Total") %>%
    filter(str_detect(regroupement, "(Ortho|dents|vasculaire|chir)")) %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with("actes"), names_to = "year") %>%
    mutate(year = as.integer(str_remove(year, "actes_"))) %>%
    group_by(regroupement) %>%
    mutate(quantity_of_interest = value / sum(value) * c(NA, diff(value)) / value) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, quantity_of_interest, fill = regroupement)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
    labs(x = "Year", y = "Quantity of interest relative to previous year") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Explanation:

1. Remove the "Total" row (it's never a good/tidy idea to mix marginals with raw data; instead calculate marginals on the fly).
2. I randomly select some of the `regroupement` categories because keeping them all will give a very cluttered plot (you've got 28 categories).
3. Reshape `actes_*` columns from wide to long and convert the names to years by removing `"actes_"` and then using `as.integer`.
4. Calculate the quantity of interest; because data is in long format we can use `group_by` with `diff` to calculate this very easily as `value / sum(value) * c(NA, diff(value)) / value`. Note that since we group by `regroupement`, `sum(value)` is simply the total per `regroupement`. If you instead want the grand total (I am not so clear on this point), you need to remove the `group_by()` and `ungroup()` lines.
5. Plot as column plot with `position = "dodge"`.

Comment: it is perfect, thanks for the great explanation ! Would you know too how to resize the key of the legend in order for it to fit in the plot ?

Comment: @user19304348 You're very welcome. Regarding resizing, there are a couple of options. You can try changing the legend width through `legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm")` inside `theme()`.  Or you can try stacking legend entries vertically; or introduce line breaks for long `regroupement` categories using e.g. `stringr::str_wrap()`. I guess the best solution depends on the data you're showing and will require some manual fine-tuning.

Comment: ok, ill try that, thanks a lot ! Just to be sure : the previous code computes the contribution on periods 2019-2020 and 2020-2021, right ?

Comment: @user19304348 Yes. The 2019-2020 difference is under 2020. The 2020-2021 difference under 2021.